"warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release" when building Flutter app
EDIT: There is a similarly titled question but it is not asking the same thing (for the root cause) and it actually makes things more confusing because it is happing to them (they say) with Gradle version 8.1 and it only happened to me after moving from Gradle 8.3 to 8.5... and also the OP of that question has not accepted an answer.
I recently upgraded the gradle wrapper version of a flutter project's android/ component(?) by doing:
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 8.5

And when I built after that using "flutter run", I got some new warninga that I did not get before:
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

This warning was repeated about 10 times (I'm assuming each repetition corresponds the build.gradle file of each plugin?).
The build still worked.
But I am trying to understand Java and Gradle.  So what does this error mean?
These are my assumptions:

The error originates from Gradle (and not the Android Gradle Plugin).

The error is caused by this section of at least one module's build.gradle file:
  android {

      compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
          targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
      } ... 
  }



It may have something to do with this paragraph of the Gradle Compatibility Matrix page:

"Executing the Gradle daemon with JVM 16 or earlier has been
deprecated and will become an error in Gradle 9.0. The Gradle wrapper,
Gradle client, Tooling API client, and TestKit client will remain
compatible with JVM 8."

I don't know what a Gradle "daemon" is.  If it means "gradle itself" then I don't see how a build.gradle config would affect it or have anything to do with it.
What does the error mean and what is the proper way to deal with it?

There is a similarly titled question but you didn't say which one of the many similar questions in [so].

This question is similar to: How to resolve "source value 8 is obsolete" warning in Android Studio?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
